# Calculation Based On PickList Value

Tags: apex, trigger

I have an 2 filed's name (Amount Old & Amount New) - Currency type

And a Pick list [PRICE LIST], containing 3 Values (Profit , Non-Profit and Loss

If PRICE LIST = Profit
 (Amount New = Amount Old)

If PRICE LIST = Non-Profit
 (Amount New = Amount Old * 0.50)

If PRICE LIST = Loss
   (Amount New = Amount Old * 0.25)

How to achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Should be a pretty straightforward `CASE` formula:

```
Amount_Old__c * CASE(Price_List__c,
    'Profit', 1,
    'Non-Profit, .5,
    'Loss', .25
0)
```